# Is addTextChangedListener() still in the Android api?

Tags: java, android

I am using a book from 2013, *Android How To Program* 2<sup>nd</sup> Edition by Deitel and Harvey, they are using a method `addTextChangedListener()` to set up the listener for the `TextWatcer`, is this method still in the api?

I can't find any info on it on the Android developer doc.

```
//set amountEditText's TextWatcher
EditText amountEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);
amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(amountEditTextWatcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

> is this method still in the api

Yes, [you inherit it from `TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView#addtextchangedlistener), the superclass of `EditText`.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? Its not on the Android docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

Comment: He gave you a direct link (which you could've found by Googling the method name).

Comment: I already tried googling it

Comment: I already tried googling it thats the first thing  I did you try googling the method name its not in android docs

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks I did try googling it it did not come up in android docs it was only showing me TextWatcher, I did the same thing for .setOnSeekBarChangeListener() I can't find its class either this voting system on stack is so funny of course I would try googling it

Comment: *"I already tried googling it"* - maybe you need to be a bit more clever about how you search.  Go to https://developer.android.com/reference and you will see a search box.  In the search box enter the name of the method you are searching for.  The `TextView` class is the first class in the search results ... for me.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a book from 2013, *Android How To Program 2nd Edition* by Deitel and Harvey, they are using a method `addTextChangedListener()` to set up the listener for the `TextWatcher`, is this method still in the API?

The code that you quoted in your question is calling `addTextChangedListener` on `amountEditText` which is an `EditView` object. In other words, it is setting the `amountEditTextWatcher` as the text watcher for the `EditView` ... like the comment says.

You don't set a listener for a watcher. A watcher is a kind of listener. You set a listener / watcher on (for example) a view.

So basically, the code in the book is not doing what you think.

And the reason that you can't find `addTextChangedListener` on `TextWatcher` is that that interface has **never** had such a method.  It is a method on `EditView` inherited from `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can see this sample.**

```
 yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  
      
                @Override  
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {  
                    System.out.println(cs); //This is your live editing text.
                }  
      
                @Override  
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"before text change",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                }  
      
                @Override  
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"after text change",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                }  
            });
```